# Autoexpect hang at the end of the script

Tags: expect

I'm running the following autoexpect script

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect -f

set force_conservative 0  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
                          ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
        set send_slow {1 .1}
        proc send {ignore arg} {
                sleep .1
                exp_send -s -- $arg
        }
}

set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000


send -- "ssh f.olivieri@10.255.255.1\r"
expect -exact "Password: "
send -- "C4n4r1Wh4rf!!!\r"
expect -exact "887VA#"
send -- "show interface vlan 2\r"
expect -exact "Vlan2 is up, line protocol is up \r"
send -- "logout\r"
expect eof
```

When I run it, seems that it doesn't terminate itself correctly and I don't have back my bash shell. Only If I press ctrl+c i get my terminal

```
[...]
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
887VA#logout
Connection to 10.255.255.1 closed by remote host.
Connection to 10.255.255.1 closed.
root@blackbox:/etc/myscripts#
I don t have
my bahs
shell
^Croot@blackbox:/etc/myscripts#
-bash: I: command not found
root@blackbox:/etc/myscripts#
```

This is a problem for me because I need to run that script within a bash script and save the output on txt file and then edit it

Comment: Why are you spawning a shell and then ssh? Why not just spawn `ssh` directly?

Comment: already answered at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257503/4667